# CSS, Js & images don't load when cloudflare is used

Tags: apache, cloudflare

When i use cloudflare, images, css & javascript url from my page return a 522 timeout error in http. It means that images, css & javascript aren't loaded from Apache 2.4. On the other hand, i can see the text from the page.

However, i have switched of minify, rocket loader and even tried in dev. mode.
On website site, i turned off plugins.

The firewall is also off.

Everything is fine when the domain directly point to the nameserver from the web host.

Comment: Contact cloudflare support.

Comment: @CBroe I will do because, there is the same problem from Nginx and Apache

Comment: @CBroe The explanation was pretty surprising. see below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to bad settings for 2 IP addresses in interface file from Centos 7.

Here is what caused 522 errors for Css, Js and images:

```
IPADDR0=X.X.X.1
IPADDR1=X.X.X.2
PREFIX=26
```

After:

```
IPADDR0=X.X.X.1
PREFIX0=26
IPADDR1=X.X.X.2
PREFIX1=26
```